# Практическая разница между подходами к наследованию в Entity Framework при разработке

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Здравствуйте ,изучая материалы по Entity Framework прочитал о возможностях и разных подходах при реализации наследования в данном фреймворке . И меня конечно же заинтересовал такой вопрос :

***Какая разница между их использованием и реализацией при разработке?***

Какие же пункты я буду освещать при формировании ответа  :

1. *Теория* - здесь я буду рассказывать какие собственно есть подходы и как они отличаются в плане реализации
2. *Практика* - здесь я буду показывать саму реализацию кода модели классов **+** покажу как будет выглядеть таблица/таблицы баз данных при разных подходах
3. *Характеристическое сравнение* - в заключительном участке мы с вами выясним какой же подход ,в какой категории и **почему** именно этому подходу дано предпочтение .

***Значение данной статьи*** : пока изучал ,собственно, эти же подходы ,то в голову сразу пришла идея создать пособие где **каждый** может наглядно увидеть разницу при их использовании и на основе характеристик и практических примеров увидеть и решить для себя какой именно подход будет оптимальным

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Итак ,начнем пожалуй .

***Теоретическая часть :***

Всего в `Entity Framework` есть всего 3 подхода :

1. TPH (Table Per Hierarchy - Таблица на одну иерархию классов)
2. TPT (Table Per Type - Таблица на тип)
3. TPC (Table Per Class(Concrete Type) - Таблица на каждый отдельный тип/класс)

**1)** *TPH* (Table Per Hierarchy - Таблица на одну иерархию классов) - При использовании данного подхода - для одной иерархии классов используется одна таблица.

Данные базовых и производных классов сохраняются в одну таблицу, а для их отличия создается специальный столбец.

**2)** *TPT* (Table Per Type - Таблица на тип) - данный подход предполагает сохранение в общей таблице только тех свойств, которые общие для всех классом-наследников, то есть которые определены в базовом классе.

А те свойства, которые относятся только к производному классу, сохраняются в отдельной таблице.

**3)** *TPC* (Table Per Class(Concrete Type) - Таблица на каждый отдельный тип/класс) - предполагает создание для каждой модели по отдельной таблицы. Столбцы в каждой таблице создаются по всем свойствам, в том числе и унаследованным.

*Здесь мы с теоретической частью пожалуй закончим - перейдем до практики*:

***Практическая часть:***

Я считаю ,что надо выяснить **одну** деталь сразу :

*Суть и предназначение у этих подходов **одна** - отобразить зависимость класса-наследника от класса-родителя и **разность** заключается в том ,что я буду показывать какой именно подход будет оптимальней с разных характеристических сторон(ну и само собою - отличия при их практической реализации). Спасибо за внимание!*

**1) Подход TPH :**

Итак у нас есть базовая мини-иерархия двух классов :

```
    public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class Smartphone : Phone
{
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

class MobileContext : DbContext
{
    public MobileContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Smartphone> Smarts { get; set; }
}
```

Здесь класс `Smartphone` наследуется от `Phone`, определяя одно свойство в дополнение к унаследованным.

И при работе будет создана такая таблица:

[image: Вид таблицы при подходе TPH]

Кроме всех свойств классов `Phone` и `Smartphone` здесь также появляется еще один столбец - `Discriminator`. Он имеет тип `nvarchar` и имеет длину в 128 символов. Данный столбец и будет определять относится строка к типу `Phone` или `Smartphone`.

*Работа в программе :*

```
using(MobileContext db = new MobileContext())
{
    db.Phones.Add(new Phone {Name = "Samsung Galaxy S5", Company = "Samsung", Price = 14000 });
    db.Phones.Add(new Phone {Name = "Nokia Lumia 630", Company = "Nokia", Price = 8000 });

    Smartphone s1 = new Smartphone { Name = "iPhone 6", Company = "Apple", Price = 32000, OS = "iOS" };
    db.Smarts.Add(s1);
    db.SaveChanges();

    foreach (Phone p in db.Phones)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) - {2}", p.Name, p.Company, p.Price);
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (Smartphone p in db.Smarts)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}, {2}) - {3}", p.Name, p.Company, p.Price, p.OS);
}
```

**Прошу вас обратить внимание на одну деталь :** при выводе данных из `Phones` также будет идти вывод экземпляра `Smartphone` вместе с остальными экземплярами ,поскольку здесь `SmartPhone` и есть объектом `Phone`.

**2) Подход TPT :**

Чтобы применить подход, возьмем из предыдущего примера систему классов и добавим к классу `Smartphone` атрибут `[Table]`:

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
[Table("Smartphones")]
public class Smartphone : Phone
{
    public string OS { get; set; }
}
class MobileContext : DbContext
{
    public MobileContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Smartphone> Smarts { get; set; }
}
```

Все остальное остается также, как и при подходе **TPH**. Но теперь база данных будет содержать следующие таблицы:

[image: Подход TPT]

Таблица для смартфонов содержит только одно поле `OS`, а также ключ `Id` для связи с таблицей `Phones`.

Применение моделей будет аналогично подходу **TPH(пункт выше)**:

```
using(MobileContext db = new MobileContext())
{
    db.Phones.Add(new Phone {Name = "Samsung Galaxy S5", Company = "Samsung", Price = 14000 });
    db.Phones.Add(new Phone {Name = "Nokia Lumia 630", Company = "Nokia", Price = 8000 });

    Smartphone s1 = new Smartphone { Name = "iPhone 6", Company = "Apple", Price = 32000, OS = "iOS" };
    db.Smarts.Add(s1);
    db.SaveChanges();

    foreach (Phone p in db.Phones)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) - {2}", p.Name, p.Company, p.Price);
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (Smartphone p in db.Smarts)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}, {2}) - {3}", p.Name, p.Company, p.Price, p.OS);
}
```

**3) Подход TPC :**

Чтобы применить подход, изменим объявления моделей и контекст следующим образом:

```
public class Phone
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated (DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

public class Smartphone : Phone
{
    public string OS { get; set; }
}

class MobileContext : DbContext
{
    public MobileContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Smartphone> Smarts { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Phone>()
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Phones");
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Smartphone>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Smarts");
        });
    }
}
```

**Во-первых**, обратите внимание, что у класса `Phone` в качестве типа ключа используется не `int`, а `Guid`. Это поможет нам избежать некоторых проблем с ключами. Хотя также можно было бы использовать `int` с ручной установкой `Id` при создании объекта.

**Во-вторых**, при настройке сопоставления моделей и таблиц у каждой модели вызывается метод `MapInheritedProperties()`, который указывает `Entity Framework`-у, что в таблицу для данной модели надо включить также наследуемые свойства, а не только те, которые определены непосредственно в этой модели.

При генерации базы данных у нас будут созданы две таблицы с полным набором столбцов:

[image: подход TPC]

Применение моделей:

```
using(MobileContext db = new MobileContext())
{
    db.Phones.Add(new Phone {Name = "Samsung Galaxy S5", Company = "Samsung", Price = 14000 });
    db.Phones.Add(new Phone {Name = "Nokia Lumia 630", Company = "Nokia", Price = 8000 });

    Smartphone s1 = new Smartphone { Name = "iPhone 6", Company = "Apple", Price = 32000, OS = "iOS" };
    db.Smarts.Add(s1);
    db.SaveChanges();

    foreach (Phone p in db.Phones)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) - {2}", p.Name, p.Company, p.Price);
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (Smartphone p in db.Smarts)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}, {2}) - {3}", p.Name, p.Company, p.Price, p.OS);
}
```

**Несмотря на то, что** объект `Smartphone` никак не связан с таблицей `Phones`, при извлечении данных он также будет находится в наборе `db.Phones`, потому что наследование все равно будет действовать.

*Переходим к третьей части - **Характеристическое сравнение :***

**Вот тут уже действительно интересно:**  В зависимости от ваших требований и требований заказчика - здесь попросту **нет**  'лучшего'  решения **...** **Но:**

Движок `Entity Framework` хоть и поддерживает подход **TPC** , **но** для его адекватной работы нам нужно метод `OnModelCreating()` **переопределять** , дабы фреймворк понял, что мы подвязываем два класса между собою наследственными связями - чтобы можно было нормально работать с результатом запросов используя этот подход в приложении .

Значит ли это то ,что в большинстве случаев нам будет придеться использовать 2-а первых подхода - **TPH** и **TPT** ,чтобы не тратить время на изощрения с **TPC** и относительную скорость работы приложения при получении запросов?

***Давайте выясним!***

Итак ,здесь мы использовать формат **"критерий - условный победитель - почему"** :

1. **Скорость исполнения(работы)** - **TPH** -> *Таблица на одну иерархию* классов в общем имеет лучшую скорость хотя бы **потому ,что** на не надо делать запросы `JOIN` поскольку все данные в одной таблице . Такое решение становиться даже **более очевидным** ,*когда у нас наследственная иерархия делается "шире" и "глубже"*.
2. **Гибкость** - **TPT** -> *Таблица на тип* более гибкая потому,что решает проблему редактирования и обновлений колонок дочерней-таблицы при этом не изменяя родительскую таблицу.
3. **Эстетичность** - **TPT** -> это уже чисто субъективное мнение ,но как по-мне ,то *TPT* выглядит для мене более объектно-ориентированным подходом.
4. **Использование памяти** - **TPT** -> если у вас иерархия наследования имеет очень много различных типов , то использование *TPT* позволит использовать данные ,которые имеют много незаполненных полей , **тем более** ,если структура баз данных решает проблему множества пустых полей ,то эта проблема вряд ли скажется на производительности работы запросов.

***Как мы с вами можем заметить ,если вы или ваш заказчик знает на какой критерий делать упор - то вы можете сделать очевидный выбор исходя из информации выше***

*Единственный нюанс состоит в том ,что в 90% случаев ставка идет на **Производительность**,поэтому в большинстве случаев использование TPH(Таблица на одну иерархию) для оптимизации работы запросов - будет оптимальней*

Надеюсь ,я этой статьей смог внести немного ясности в вопрос - если у вас есть пожелания ,то комментарии всегда открыты для вас - *Спасибо за внимание,комрады!*

Само собой ссылки на источники : [практические примеры и использование данных подходов в приложениях](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/7.1.php) + [отличительные характеристики каждого из подходов](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/04/14/tip-12-how-to-choose-an-inheritance-strategy/)